# Не открывается модальное окно Bootstarp 4

Tags: bootstrap4

Использую стандартный код Bootstrap 4. На одном сайте работает, на другом нет. В чем может быть причина?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/bootstrap.bundle.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/bootstrap.css" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/all.css" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#EditTransaction">Open modal</button>
    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="EditTransaction" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="ModalEditTransactionLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="ModalEditTransactionLabel">Редактирование транзакции</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body"></div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Закрыть без сохранения</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Сохранить изменения</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- EndModal -->
</div>
</body>
<footer>

</footer>
</html>
```

Делаю на стартовом шаблоне Bootstrap 5, модальное окно открывается.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <!-- Обязательные метатеги -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
<!-- Дополнительный JavaScript; выберите один из двух! -->

<!-- Вариант 1: Bootstrap в связке с Popper -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!-- Вариант 2: Bootstrap JS отдельно от Popper
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-IQsoLXl5PILFhosVNubq5LC7Qb9DXgDA9i+tQ8Zj3iwWAwPtgFTxbJ8NT4GN1R8p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-cVKIPhGWiC2Al4u+LWgxfKTRIcfu0JTxR+EQDz/bgldoEyl4H0zUF0QKbrJ0EcQF" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
-->

<div class="container">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#EditTransaction">Open modal</button>
    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="EditTransaction" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="ModalEditTransactionLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="ModalEditTransactionLabel">Редактирование транзакции</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body"></div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Закрыть без сохранения</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Сохранить изменения</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- EndModal -->
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос закрыт. Все дело в **data-bs-toggle** и **data-bs-target** они используются как раз в Bootstrap 5. А в Bootstrap 4 надо использовать **data-toggle** и **data-target**.